# CryptEncrypt AES 256 fails at encrypting last block

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption

First of all, I apologize if I'm missing something here. This is my first every attempt at the Windows CryptAPI, and although I have gone through google, MSDN, MSDN's examples, etc. I cannot figure out why this problem is happening.
I have the following code which is supposed to copy opcode (blocks of bytes) found at a specific address, encrypt them, and then write them back. It is by no means a complete code and it does very little error checking. I am using AES256.

```
bool CryptoClass::encrypt(DWORD address, DWORD len)
{
    DWORD dwBlockLen = 0; 
    DWORD dwBufferLen = 0; 
    DWORD dwCount = 0; 
    PBYTE pbBuffer = NULL;    
    dwBlockLen = AES_BLOCK_SIZE - AES_BLOCK_SIZE % ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE; 
    dwBufferLen = dwBlockLen + ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE; 
    if(pbBuffer = (BYTE *)malloc(dwBufferLen))
    {
        bool EOB = FALSE;
        while ( dwCount <= len) )
        {
            memcpy((void*)pbBuffer,(void*)address,dwBlockLen);              
            if ( (len - dwCount) < dwBlockLen) EOB = TRUE;              

            if(CryptEncrypt(hKey,NULL,EOB,0,pbBuffer,&dwBlockLen,dwBufferLen))
            {
                memcpy((void*)address,(void*)pbBuffer,dwBlockLen);
                address += dwBlockLen;                              
                dwCount += dwBlockLen;                              
            }
            else
            {
                error = GetLastError();
                MessageBoxA(NULL,"problem","error",MB_OK);
            }
        }
        free(pbBuffer);
       return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

From my understanding AES can encrypt blocks of 16 bytes, so AES_BLOCK_SIZE is defined to 16.
Also my ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE is set to 8. I am basically copying an example I found on MSDN, and adjusting for AES256 and for use with memory instead of a file.
However in my while loop, whenever it reaches the end of the buffer, where the FINAL is set to TRUE, the CryptEncrypt fails. I have tried many different ways to do this but it always fails.
Is it because the buffer at the end is less than 16bytes ?
Can some please help, I am a total noob when it comes to encryption.
Thank you
EDIT: GetLastError returns: 0x000000ea

Comment: What the heck does ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE do? Do you have a pointer to the example used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the error ERROR_MORE_DATA. Which translates into:

If the buffer allocated for pbData is not large enough to hold the encrypted data, GetLastError returns ERROR_MORE_DATA and stores the required buffer size, in bytes, in the DWORD value pointed to by pdwDataLen.

If the method uses CBC encryption (Microsoft, in it's wisdom, does not specify a mode OR padding algorithm in their API) then the following algorithm should be performed to calculate the output size of the buffer:

buffer_size = (plain_size_bytes / AES_BLOCK_SIZE + 1) * AES_BLOCK_SIZE;

In other words, if plain_size_bytes is N * AES_BLOCK_SIZE you still need a full block of padding. This is because you always need to perform padding, otherwise the unpadding algorithm cannot distinquish you plain text from padding bytes.

Of course, you could also simply create a buffer of plain_size_bytes + AES_BLOCK_SIZE and use the pdwDataLen value to get the actual length.

EDIT: if you encrypt each plain text block separately, and the cipher uses CBC or ECB with padding, then the last plain block may require 2 whole blocks because of above

Comment: Thanks that was it indeed. I just used a bigger buffer & block size and solved it. Apparently I also had to :
    CryptSetKeyParam(hKey, KP_MODE,(BYTE*)&dwMode, NULL);
Which sets the ECB mode. Thank you for your explanation though :)

Comment: ECB mode encryption is unsafe in almost all circumstances. It can use the same padding mechanisms as CBC (PKCS#7 padding is used most of the time), so the answer is valid for both. Use CBC instead of ECB and prepend your cipher text with a random IV to be safe(r).

Comment: I've waisted 3 days trying to figure out why the ciphertext would not decrypt when using ECB. Switching to CBC it worked on the first try. I wish I had read your comment earlier, would have saved me the trouble...

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( address < (address + len) )
```

My cryptic answer is "think about it -- you won't quite think about it forever, but..."

Comment: yeah, I just realized, too tired to spot this. Thanks !
However this does not solve the problem of why the CryptEncrypt fails at the last block.

Comment: It might have explained why CryptEncrypt failed after the last block, but not any more after you edited your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( (len - dwCount) < dwBlockLen) EOB = TRUE;
```

maybe should be something like

```
if ( (len - dwCount) < dwBlockLen)
{
    EOB = TRUE;
    dwBlockLen = ENCRYPT_BLOCK_SIZE;
}
```